# XDebug with PHP Unit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to get XDebug to work with PHP Unit. I use PhpStorm on OSX.

Here was my approach: I took the contents of the phpunit shell script and create anew file in /usr/local/bin called php-xdebug. In that file I added the config flags for xdebug. Needless to say I haven't been able to hit a break point in my IDE or I wouldn't be posting this message.

Here's the content of php-xdebug:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/env php -d xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM -d xdebug.remote_enable=1 -d xdebug.remote_port=9000 -d xdebug.remote_host=localhost -d xdebug.remote_autostart=1 -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/4.3.4/libexec/phpunit-4.3.4.phar $*
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Had to load the extension using zend_extension.

Comment: When in doubt, the XDebug page has a section for you to post your PHP.INI, and it will mark up the changes you need.  http://xdebug.org/wizard.php